# Different proof that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

If $H\leq G$ and $[G:H]=2$ then $H$ is normal in $G$.

---

The simplest proof I can think of is that if $gH\neq Hg$ and $|H|=|G|/2$ then because $gH$ and $Hg$  have also order $|G|/2$, we have $|H|=|gH|=|Hg|$ but that would mean $[G:H]=3$, thus $gH = Hg$

Or even we can say that since the groups $H,gH,Hg $ have all order $|G|/2$
then the elements of those subroups would be $\frac{|G|}{2}-1+\frac{|G|}{2}-1+\frac{|G|}{2}>|G|$ so it must be $gH = Hg$.

Is this right? Or am i missing something?

Comment: The original result holds for infinite group

Comment: The proofs are all wrong.

Comment: On what basis do you get from $|H|=|gH|=|Hg|$ (with $gH\not= Hg$) to $[G:H]=3$? (I suspect you might be thinking that $H$, $gH$ and $Hg$ are mutually disjoint if $gH\not=Hg$. But keep in mind that $g\in gH\cap Hg$.)

Comment: @markvs from the mistakes I learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proofs you gave are incorrect. The left cosets partition $G$ and the right cosets partition $G$, but these are completely separate partitions. In particular, you can't conclude that $H, gH, Hg$ are disjoint.

The easiest proof is that if $g \notin H$, then $gH \neq H$, and since it must be disjoint from $H$, we must have $gH = G \setminus H$ (since the left cosets $\{H,gH\}$ form a partition). The same argument shows that $Hg = G \setminus H$ and hence $gH = Hg$, so that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Intuitively or even "geometrically" with a picture-sphape  how you think about it?

Comment: Also, the fact that if $g\notin H$ then  $gH\neq H$ its true because $H\leq G$ ?

Comment: One way to think about it geometrically: $H$ is some shape which tiles (as in, tiling the plane) the group $G$. However, in general, there are two distinct ways to tile (i.e., corresponding to left and right cosets), but in each of these $H$ itself is one of the tiles (since $eH = H$). The idea is that if $[G:H] = 2$ (i.e., there are two tiles), then $H$ is one of the tiles, and so the other tile must be the other left (or right!) coset.

Comment: @lupusnox: $gH\neq H$ is true because $g\in gH$ but $g\notin H$, because $e\in H$. It actually doesn't depend on $H$ being a subgroup, just on $e\in H$ being true. That you have a partition of $G$ follows because $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Recall that $g \in H$ if and only if $gH = H$. More generally, $g_1^{-1} g_2 \in H$ if and only if $g_1 H = g_2 H$.

Comment: You are the best thank you !

Comment: Why for finite groups only?

Comment: @CAB: yes, of course, the argument works for infinite groups too. I assumed finite mainly because the OP did implicitly. I have edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $H\leq G$ Such that  $[G:H]=2 $ it means there
are only 2 left cosets of $H$ in $G$

Let $a\in G $ such that $a\notin H$

Then $G=H\cup aH$ then $a^2\in H \Rightarrow a^2=h \; \forall \; a\notin H$

Then for any $x\notin H$
$xhx^{-1}=xx^2x^{-1}=x^2\in H$
Hence for every $x\in G  $ and $h\in H\; xhx^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow H\triangleleft G$